# How can I get the resume date of a Task Assignment in code?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins, ms-project

I'm writing a script that needs to check the resume dates of resource assignments on a given task. You can see the resume dates of resource assignments in the task usage view of MS Project:

[image: MS Project Task Usage]

I need to check the Resume date for each assignment because they can potentially be different than the task's resume date:

[image: task usage view 2]

In the MS Project API, the *Assignment* object doesn't seem to be able to access the *Resume* value, even though it can access most other fields for assignments.

[image: Issue]

Is there a way to access the *Resume* date of a Resource Assignment in code without needing to actually select the assignment in the task usage view?

Comment: Do you see different dates for different assignments? It appears that [Resume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task.resume) is at the task level, not assignment level.

Comment: @RachelHettinger they can be different in this instance:  1. The task is in progress 2. a task has multiple resource assignments 3. a user has set the remaining work of at least 1 of the resource assignments to 0 but also has at least one resource assignment that has remaining work greater than 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Resume date for an assignment is the next working day after the last day with Actual Work for that assignment. Here's a vba sample that should readily convert to c#:

```
Function FindResumeDate(a As Assignment) As Variant

    If a.ActualWork = 0 Then
        FindResumeDate = "NA"
    Else
    
        Dim tsvs As TimeScaleValues
        Set tsvs = a.TimeScaleData(a.Start, a.Finish, pjAssignmentTimescaledActualWork, pjTimescaleDays)
        
        Dim i As Long
        i = tsvs.Count + 1
        Do
            i = i - 1
        Loop Until i = 1 Or VarType(tsvs(i).Value) = vbDouble
        
        Dim resDate As Date
        If a.RemainingWork = 0 Then
            resDate = tsvs(i).StartDate
        Else
            resDate = Fix(Application.DateAdd(tsvs(i).StartDate, 481))
        End If
        
        FindResumeDate = resDate
        
    End If
    
End Function
```